# Почему я не могу использовать using в данной ситуации?

Tags: c++

```
struct undefined_concept {};

struct polygon_concept {};

template <typename T>
struct geometry_concept { typedef undefined_concept type; };


//struct geometry_concept<int>{ typedef polygon_concept type; }; /*Это работает*/
template <> using geometry_concept<int> = polygon_concept; /*expected an identifier*/
```

Comment: потому что такого синтаксиса нет. А как это все хочется использовать потом?

Comment: похоже, Вы ищите где то такое `template <> struct geometry_concept<int>{ using type = polygon_concept; };`

Comment: Как это такого синтаксиса нет ? А как же https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795023/c-template-typedef

Comment: там немного в другом месте находятся угловые скобки

Comment: Ладно, а есть идеи, зачем нужен в теории мной приведенный фрагмент кода? 
Он вырван из boost polygon библиотеки. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/polygon/doc/gtl_custom_polygon.htm
Что это за регистрация пустых типов данных, я не особо понимаю

Comment: там похоже на typetrait. когда начинается метапрограммирования, то функции превращаются в структуры. А типы в структурах это как бы возвращаемые значения (очень очень грубое определение). Зачем это нужно? ну прилетел нам в шаблон контейнер, а как узнать тип элементов? для этого есть вложенный тип с известным названием.

Comment: Потому что изначально оно объявлено как `struct geometry_concept`. Cоответственно любая специализация должна тоже быть структрурой.